# Button held down by code

Tags: c++, directx

I am writing a game and am trying to make a person move with the arrow keys.

I have this code

```
if (Key_Down(DIK_DOWN))
{movedown(player)}
```

This works but as I want the player to take four steps every time the key is pressed I created and animation loop. so the player cannot input any more move commands until the animation is over and they have taken four steps I made the code this.

```
if(player.move == false)
{
if (Key_Down(DIK_DOWN))
{movedown(player)}
}
```

The problem is that now once a button is pressed the program acts like the button is held down and the player keeps moving until another direction is pressed.

Can anyone explain what the outer loop has done to the code and fix the problem ?

it is programmed in visual c++ 2005 and direct x 9.c

Edit:

If I remove the outer loop then the button press is only registered once so I don't think it is the movedown function.

Comment: What does the code inside moveDown look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep track of the keystate in a variable.  So you can reset a move counter.  Something like this, combining both:

```
int MovingDown = 0;
...
if (!Key_Down(DIK_DOWN)) MovingDown = 0;
else if (MovingDown < 4) {
    MovingDown++;
    movedown(player);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it still executes the if statment contents when movingdown is > 4. also I has a hack where the movedown function checks if player.move is false but this incurs processor time as the function needs to be called every loop for every object whether or not it should be.

Comment: I like my version of C++ better than yours, at least if() statements behave predictably when I use them.

Comment: It only misbehaves when it is a nested if statement

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing more of your codebase but I would guess that you're not re-setting `player.move` after you've moved the player. Have you tried sticking some break poins in there to see what is being called and why?

If you remove the `if(player.move == false)` line does it have the same issue? ..or have you changed something elsewhere? If you could post more of your codebase like the whole movedown function and anythnig else which interacts (e.g. the animation code) it would help us help you...

*[Edit]* Is movedown a macro? Maybe you've got some peculiar side effect eminating from that? If not, it ought to have a semi colon after the function call.

What does KEY_DOWN return? Is that an API call? Try testing against the exact value you expect it to return?

Comment: I am resetting player.move and I have break pointed it. everything works as it should according to my logic but once the if (Key_Down(DIK_DOWN)) statement is read as true once it will always execute from that point on no matter what.

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with using an if statement. The artifact you're seeing here is going to be caused by something else. If you're not prepared to post more code, there's not much more stabbing around in the dark we can offer I'm afraid.